# Retrieve data from two tables with many to many relationship in Django?

Tags: database, django

I want to retrieve a data which has user id 1 from the table called file. The user and file table and many to many relationship. I want to show the file related to that user.

```
class GalaxyUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=765)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'

class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(GalaxyUser)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.TextField()
    end_date = models.TextField()
    duration = models.TextField()
    size = models.TextField()
    flag = models.TextField()
```

If the user is logged in as user, I get the user_id let's say it's 1. Now, I want to retrieve the file name related to user 1 only. How can I do that?

Comment: If you want a single file name related to a user, you're using the wrong datastructure: you want a OneToOne relationship, not a ManyToMany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.objects.filter(users=GalaxyUser.objects.get(id=1))
```

Comment: It would help the user (and other readers) if you explained your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File.objects.filter(users__id__exact=1)`. Refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Answer (score 1):

```
user = GalaxyUser.objects.get(id=1)
files = user.file_set.all()
```

See more about ManyToMany lookups [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)